# PageMethods not working because method is not calling from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a page method,

```
 PageMethods.AuthUser(username,password,onsuccess, on fail);
```

My codebehind is following

```
public string AuthUser(string username,string password){return ""}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong it's just not working

Comment: have u tried static on ur web method

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got it I was missing static on my code behind method and I figured out that method supposed to be with webmethod. Thanks xyz for comment

it should have been

```
[WebMethod]
public static AuthUser(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ScriptManager property `EnablePageMethods="true"`

**Change your code**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AuthUser(string username,string password){return ""}
```